# SQL Server split datetime column

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, datetime, split, mondrian

I'm trying to split a `datetime` column in my SQL Server database. All entries are in the format: `yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.0` (yes, every time dimension is uselessly the same, but there's nothing I can do about it, it's not my db).

Actually, what I really want to do is to create a new time dimension with 4 columns: `Date`, `Year`, `Month` and `Day` (that's because I need to form a Mondrian hierarchy based on that time dimension).

I really don't know how to to this, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `Datetime` has no _format_, it has just a value which always contains the time portion.

Comment: Well, I'm sorry for the theoretical misunderstanding, but the rest of the question remains the same.

Comment: Are you trying to alter the format of the table  to add year, month and day columns and then update the new columns with the appropriate value from the date column?

Comment: `datepart` and `day` should all get you there

Comment: [DATEPART](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174420.aspx) should do it (along with a cast to `DATE`)  -  `SELECT Date = CAST(DateTime AS DATE), Year = DATEPART(YEAR, DateTime), Month = DATEPART(MONTH, DateTime), Day = DATEPART(DAY, DateTime);`

Comment: Kevin, that's not quite what I'm aiming. I don't want to alter the table but to create a new one that should have the date column (Foreign from the old one) and the 3 other columns that are the split of the date.

Comment: Thank you, LittleBobby and Gareth, I'm gonna give it a shot and reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select DateTimeCol, DATEPART(YEAR, DateTimeCol) as YearCol, DATEPART(MONTH, DateTimeCol) as MonthCol, DATEPART(DAY, DateTimeCol) as DayCol 
into NewTable
from OldTable
```

Comment: I was about to post the same, but it's better coming from you. Thanks a Lot, Kevin!